# How would I make this iframe lose its borders/scrollbars and resize to fit a DIV?

Tags: iframe, html

I've tried what other people have said and it doesn't seem to work. Could you possibly code it yourself? I'm really frustrated.

```
<a href="#computing" onclick="document.getElementById('MainBack').innerHTML = '<iframe src=\'test.html\'></iframe>'">Computing</a>
```

Here is the place I would like it:

http://markbrewerton.co.uk/work.html#computing

Answer (score 0):

Use a CSS rule like this to make the iframe fill it's parent and have no border:

```
#MainBack iframe { width: 100%; height: 100%; border: none; }
```

Internet Explorer doesn't respect the `border` setting, so you also need to set the `frameborder` attribute in the tag:

```
<a href="#computing" onclick="document.getElementById('MainBack').innerHTML = '<iframe src=&quot;test.html&quot; frameborder=&quot;0&quot;></iframe>'">Computing</a>
```

Comment: @Mark Brewerton: The containing element needs to have a specific height set, or the height setting of the iframe won't have any effect. Alternatively you can specify a set height for the iframe if the containing element will adjust to it.

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<iframe src="" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
```

CSS

```
border:none;
overflow:hidden;
width:450px;
height:35px;"
```

Allowtransparecy is used in IE otherwise you'll see a background different from the page background..

EDIT:
added the escaped version

```
<a href="#computing" onclick="document.getElementById('MainBack').innerHTML = '<iframe src=\'http://www.google.com\'  scrolling=\'no\' frameborder=\'0\' allowtransparency=\'true\'></iframe>'">Computing</a>    
<div id="MainBack"></div>
```

Comment: When I do that, the link for it (computing) displays like this:       ">Computing         and no longer works

Comment: you must escape the doublequote :)

Comment: Now it displays as - '>Computing

Comment: Thanks. That works. But I have the same problem as the other answer. A big gap underneath it. Is there a way to resize the parent div so that it is tight against the content of the iFrame?

Comment: using css set the same width/height to the div and the iframe :) can you set my answer as accepted? :P